# How can I specify that my project requres PHP 5.x or HHVM 3.x with Composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, hhvm

How can I specify that my project requires PHP 5.x or HHVM 3.x with Composer?

Something as:

```
"require":{
  ...
  "php":"~5.3" OR "hhvm":"~3.2" ,
  .....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/751

They are working on it!